“Aunty better watch how she talks—scratch most folks in Maycomb and they’re kin to us.”
When reading "To Kill a Mocking Bird" by Harper Lee I stumbled upon a sentence that completely stumped me.(the quotation sentence) I don't know who is talking and what they are talking about. The only thing I was able to figure out about the sentence is that when the person speaking is using the word "kin" it's supposed to convey the idea that the family of Finches (to which this person belongs) regards the people living in their town as members of their own family.

When Aunt Alexandra went to school, self-doubt could not be found in
any textbook, so she knew not its meaning. She was never bored, and
given the slightest chance she would exercise her royal prerogative:
she would arrange, advise, caution, and warn. She never let a chance
escape her to point out the shortcomings of other tribal groups to the
greater glory of our own, a habit that amused Jem rather than annoyed
him: “Aunty better watch how she talks—scratch most folks in Maycomb
and they’re kin to us.”


Aunt Alexandra is fiercely proud of the Finch family lineage, of which she's the older generation, and Jem (and Scout, the narrator) are the younger generation, who don't take such matters so seriously. Scout is saying that Aunty can't really big up her own family by being critical of other families in the area, because all the local families are (literally and/or figuratively) so closely related.

...but of course Jem is only talking about the local white population. I can't be sure, but I honestly doubt that when writing those words Harper Lee was consciously aware of the irony of making such an assertion about "most folks" all being part of the same broader "tribal" group. It's a fictional setting, but if it accurately reflected the South at the time, the local black population would probably have actually outnumbered the white folks. But they certainly don't even count as a "social lineage" within Aunt Alexandra myopic vision of local society.

"Jem" is speaking, he has just been mentioned, and the use of quote marks shows this is direct speech.
"Watch what how she talks" must refer back to Aunt Alexandra's habit of criticising other families.
"Scratch" alludes to "scratching the surface" of something to investigate what it is made of.  For example you might "scratch the surface" of something that appears to be silver and find that it is just silver-plated copper. We are talking about people's families,  so "Scratch most folks" means "investigate the family history of most people".
"Kin to us" means "related" or "in our extended family". The last part completes an implied conditional  "If you investigate,  you will find that they are in our extended family". And this explains why Anut Alexandra needs to be careful.  If she criticises other families, she is criticising her own (extended) family.

Thank you, James. That's a really nice and thorough answer :)
